Importing data from Lens into bibliometrix: Error in strsplit(DATA$AU, split = "; ") : non-character argument
I'm trying to import data from Lens into bibliometrix
I did so following the steps provided here: https://www.bibliometrix.org/vignettes/Data-Importing-and-Converting.html
file <- "FILE PATH"
M <- convert2df(file, dbsource = "lens", format = "csv") 


However, I'm getting the following error message:
Error in strsplit(DATA$AU, split = "; ") : non-character argument


Is there anything anyone could suggest?
Here's the data I'm working with:



#
Jurisdiction
Kind
Display Key
Lens ID
Publication Date
Publication Year
Application Number
Application Date
Priority Numbers
Earliest Priority Date
Title
Abstract
Applicants
Inventors
Owners
Document Type
Has Full Text
Cites Patent Count
Cited by Patent Count
Simple Family Size
Extended Family Size
Sequence Count
CPC Classifications
IPCR Classifications
US Classifications
NPL Citation Count
NPL Resolved Citation Count
NPL Resolved Lens ID(s)
NPL Resolved External ID(s)
NPL Citations
Legal Status




1
KR
A
KR 20130016644 A
133-469-477-470-810
########
2013
KR 20110078703 A
########
KR 20110078703 A
########
VOICE RECOGNITION APPARATUS, VOICE RECOGNITION SERVER, VOICE RECOGNITION SYSTEM AND VOICE RECOGNITION METHOD
PURPOSE: A voice recognition apparatus for accurately recognizing the limited vocabulary by the comparison of voice data in a voice recognition engine and voice recognition target information, a voice recognition server thereof, a voice recognition system thereof and a voice recognition method thereof are provided to accurately recognize the limited vocabulary used in a specific area even by a widely used voice recognition engine without limitation of recognizable vocabulary. CONSTITUTION: A voice input unit(110) receives voice from a user. An image processing unit(150) processes an image. A display unit(160) displays the image processing result. A control unit(120) transmits voice data and voice recognition target information to a voice recognition engine(170). The control unit receives the recognition result corresponding to the voice from the voice recognition engine. [Reference numerals] (100) Voice recognition device; (110) Voice input unit; (120) Control unit; (150) Image processing unit; (160) Display unit; (170) Voice recognition engine; (AA) Voice
SAMSUNG ELECTRONICS CO LTD
BAKE UN SANG
Patent Application
no
0
3
4
4
0
G10L15/26;;G10L2015/228;;G10L15/28;;G06F15/16;;G10L15/08;;G10L15/26;;G10L2015/228
G10L15/28;;G06F15/16;;G10L15/08
0
0



DISCONTINUED




2
US
A1
US 2013/0041666 A1
052-352-367-617-02X
########
2013
US 201213569494 A
########
KR 20110078703 A
########
VOICE RECOGNITION APPARATUS, VOICE RECOGNITION SERVER, VOICE RECOGNITION SYSTEM AND VOICE RECOGNITION METHOD
A voice recognition apparatus, a voice recognition server, a voice recognition system, and a voice recognition method, in which a general-purpose voice recognition engine may accurately recognize a limited number of words used in a specific area.
SAMSUNG ELECTRONICS CO LTD;;BAK EUN-SANG
BAK EUN-SANG
SAMSUNG ELECTRONICS CO. LTD (2012-07-30)
Patent Application
yes
26
13
4
4
0
G10L15/26;;G10L2015/228;;G10L15/28;;G06F15/16;;G10L15/08;;G10L15/26;;G10L2015/228
G10L17/00
704/246;;X704E17001
0
0



DISCONTINUED


3
CN
A
CN 102930867 A
153-327-482-348-977
########
2013
CN 201210260784 A
########
KR 20110078703 A
########
Voice recognition apparatus, voice recognition server, voice recognition system and voice recognition method
A voice recognition apparatus, a voice recognition server, a voice recognition system, and a voice recognition method, in which a general-purpose voice recognition engine may accurately recognize a limited number of words used in a specific area
SAMSUNG ELECTRONICS CO LTD
BAKE UN SANG
Patent Application
no
0
3
4
4
0
G10L15/26;;G10L2015/228;;G10L15/28;;G06F15/16;;G10L15/08;;G10L15/26;;G10L2015/228
G10L15/30

0
0



DISCONTINUED



4
JP
A
JP 2015143866 A
096-356-304-790-380
########
2015
JP 2015035108 A
########
JP 2015035108 A
########
VOICE RECOGNITION APPARATUS, VOICE RECOGNITION SYSTEM, VOICE RECOGNITION METHOD, AND VOICE RECOGNITION PROGRAM
PROBLEM TO BE SOLVED: To provide a voice recognition apparatus ensuring high responsiveness and high accuracy.SOLUTION: A voice recognition apparatus 100 comprises: recognition means 101; transmission means 103; reception means 104; recognition-result generation means 105; recognition-result storage means 106; and dictionary update means 107. The recognition means 101 generates a first recognition result using a client recognition dictionary. The transmission means 103 transmits an audio signal or a feature quantity to a server. The reception means 104 receives a second recognition result from the server. The recognition-result generation means 105 generates a third recognition result using the first recognition result if acquiring the first recognition result prior to the second recognition result and, otherwise, generates the third recognition result using at least the second recognition result. The dictionary update means 107 updates the client recognition dictionary so as to preferentially contain a first vocabulary over a second vocabulary if the history of the third recognition result includes the first vocabulary and the second vocabulary generated before the first vocabulary.
TOSHIBA CORP
KAWAMURA AKINORI;;SAKAI MASARU;;OUCHI KAZUNARI
Patent Application
no
5
2
1
1
0

G10L15/06;;G10L15/00;;G10L15/22;;G10L15/30
0
0



PENDING




5
JP
A
JP 2022096852 A
105-940-341-724-195
########
2022
JP 2020210074 A
########
JP 2020210074 A
########
VOICE RECOGNITION PROGRAM, VOICE RECOGNITION METHOD, VOICE RECOGNITION DEVICE AND VOICE RECOGNITION SYSTEM
To easily estimate the number of speakers and speakers of voices contained in an audio file without presetting.SOLUTION: In a voice recognition system in which a terminal 100 and a cloud 110 are communicatively connected, the terminal 100 has a voice recording unit 102 and a communication unit for uploading a voice file D that is recorded or played back to the cloud 110. The cloud 110 estimates the number of speakers for each speaker included in the voice file D, refers to a prepared trained model for each speaker, recognizes each speaker of the estimated number of speakers, and notifies the terminal 100 of information tagged with the speaker contained in the voice file D.SELECTED DRAWING: Figure 1
MILPLATEAUX INC
MANAI YASUHIRO;;MORISHIGE KOICHIRO
Patent Application
no
6
0
3
3
0

G10L17/00;;G10L15/00
0
0



ACTIVE




6
JP
A
JP 2014063088 A
013-671-452-957-604
########
2014
JP 2012209151 A
########
JP 2012209151 A
########
VOICE RECOGNITION DEVICE, VOICE RECOGNITION SYSTEM, VOICE RECOGNITION METHOD AND VOICE RECOGNITION PROGRAM
PROBLEM TO BE SOLVED: To develop a voice recognition device with high responsibility and high accuracy.SOLUTION: The voice recognition device comprises recognition means, transmission means, receiving means, recognition result generation means, recognition result storage means, and dictionary update means. The recognition means generates a first recognition result by using a client recognition dictionary. The transmission means transmits a voice signal or feature quantity to a server. The receiving means receives a second recognition result from the server. The recognition result generation means generates a third recognition result by using the first recognition result when acquiring the first recognition result prior to the second recognition result, otherwise the recognition result generation means generates the third recognition result by using at least the second recognition result. The dictionary update means updates the client recognition dictionary so as to include first vocabulary with higher priority than second vocabulary, when the first vocabulary and the second vocabulary generated older than the first vocabulary are included in history of the third recognition result.
TOSHIBA CORP
KAWAMURA AKINORI;;SAKAI MASARU;;OUCHI KAZUNARI
Patent Application
no
5
4
4
4
0
G10L15/30;;G10L15/183;;G10L2015/0635;;G10L15/30;;G10L15/02;;G10L15/183;;G10L2015/0635
G10L15/06;;G10L15/30
0
0



INACTIVE




7
US
A1
US 2004/0215458 A1
022-432-751-130-103
########
2004
US 83166004 A
########
JP 2003123178 A
########
Voice recognition apparatus, voice recognition method and program for voice recognition
An apparatus for recognizing a word based on voice information, includes, a keyword model storing device, a non-keyword model storing device, a model updating device and a recognition device. The keyword model storing device stores words to be potentially spoken, as keyword models. The non-keyword model storing device stores words to be potentially spoken, as non-keyword models. The model updating device updates the recognition and non-keyword models, based on a previously recognized word. The recognition device matches the recognition and non-keyword models updated with the voice information. The model updating device updates the non-keyword models utilizing a non-keyword variation vector, which is indicative of variation of the non-keyword models, from the non-updated to the updated, and has been set to be smaller than a non-keyword variation vector applied in the updating of the non-keyword models.
KOBAYASHI HAJIME;;TOYAMA SOICHI;;KAWAZOE YOSHIHIRO;;HANAI KENGO
KOBAYASHI HAJIME;;TOYAMA SOICHI;;KAWAZOE YOSHIHIRO;;HANAI KENGO
PIONEER CORPORATION (2004-05-07)
Patent Application
yes
3
50
7
7
0
G10L15/06;;G10L15/06
G10L15/20;;G10L15/06;;G10L15/07;;G10L15/08;;G10L15/10;;G10L21/0208
704/251
0
0



DISCONTINUED


8
JP
A
JP 2010191321 A
070-543-599-644-558
########
2010
JP 2009037430 A
########
JP 2009037430 A
########
VOICE RECOGNITION SYSTEM, VOICE RECOGNITION METHOD AND VOICE RECOGNITION PROGRAM
PROBLEM TO BE SOLVED: To provide a voice recognition system capable of presenting an example sentence which is useful for estimating a cause of a voice recognition error, to a user. SOLUTION: A voice recognition means 21 performs voice recognition on an input voice by using a sound model 31 and a language model 32. A word selection means 22 selects one or more words from a voice recognition result of the voice recognition means 21. A sentence creation means 23 creates a sentence by using the selected one or more words and the language model 32, and presents the created sentence to the user. COPYRIGHT: (C)2010,JPO&INPIT
NEC CORP
OSADA SEIYA;;ISOTANI RYOSUKE;;IWAZAWA TORU;;HANAZAWA TAKESHI;;TSUJIKAWA TAKENORI;;ADACHI FUMIHIRO;;ARAKAWA TAKAYUKI;;OKABE KOJI
Patent Application
no
0
1
1
1
0

G10L15/22;;G10L15/183;;G10L15/187;;G10L15/193;;G10L15/197
0
0



DISCONTINUED




9
JP
A
JP 2014178381 A
116-545-744-966-550
########
2014
JP 2013051031 A
########
JP 2013051031 A
########
VOICE RECOGNITION DEVICE, VOICE RECOGNITION SYSTEM AND VOICE RECOGNITION METHOD
PROBLEM TO BE SOLVED: To provide a voice recognition device, a voice recognition system and a voice recognition method capable of efficiently improving a voice recognition rate.SOLUTION: The voice recognition device includes a dictionary management information storage part, a dictionary storage part, a voice storage part, a call information storage part, a dictionary selection part and a voice recognition part. The dictionary storage part stores a voice recognition dictionary per operator and a voice recognition dictionary per job type. The voice storage part stores voice of each operator who has performed telephone correspondence to a user. The call information storage part stores call information associating identification information of each operator who performed telephone correspondence to a user with identification information of the type of a job that he/she is in charge of. The dictionary selection part selects a dictionary to be used for voice recognition by referring to the dictionary management information storage part on the basis of the call information. The voice recognition part converts voice of an operator read from the voice storage part into text data by referring to the selected dictionary of the dictionary storage part.
TOSHIBA CORP
TORII RYOJI

Patent Application
no
0
5
1
1
0

G10L15/06;;G10L15/00;;H04M3/42
0
0



PENDING





It would be more useful to show us the result of dput(M), or maybe str(M) if that is too big.  Showing us a table in some other system isn't going to tell us what went wrong in R, but my guess would be that your data doesn't have a column named "AU", and the message arises because of that fact.

Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a minimal reproducible example.
